# Georeferencing using corner coordinate

Tags: georeferencing, geotiff-tiff, idl

I have thousands of tiff files with meta file containing corner coordinates. All images coordinates are different as they represent different locations.
How can I georeference all these files using corner coordinates in IDL or python?
[Sample Meta file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VknZOLHJ1DV3psNzk5Q0FlZ2s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is the 'meta file' a world file (.tfw)? If so, your work is done. If not, your task is to make it one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Comment: meta data stored in a TXT file.

Comment: So, you need to get those corner coordinates, along with the other required pieces of info (pixel size and rotation[s]), into a file with the same name as the tiff, and extension .tfw. Once you've attempted a script, post it for more help.

Comment: I just worked with two images. 1 is georefereced and 2 is not but same image. I created a world file from image 1 and renamed it with image 2. It didn't work. Do you have any other idea without world file?

Comment: I would first point gdalinfo at one of the files, it may well be a GeoTIFF anyway

Comment: TFW file is perhaps not the easiest way to go because then you should know also the pixel size in X and Y axis. You can calculate the pixel size but there may a shorter route. Could you add contents of one such TXT file into your question?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VknZOLHJ1DV3psNzk5Q0FlZ2s/view?usp=sharing